# Retrieve the selected item from the menuitems of a context menu. I am using WPF, MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a context Menu on my ListView with FilterBy as one of the Menu items in it. This Menu Item is bound to an observable collection of Menuitems(_childFilterMenuitems coming from an object ContextMenuclass). I want to retrieve the selected item from the submenu of the FilterBy MenuItem and bind to a property called SelectedItem in my MainView Model.

Everything works fine with the relay command and populating the items. However I cannot access the selected item in my main view model. I tried binding the SelectedItem Property(From the MainViewModel) to the Tag Property on the Menuitem. I cannot get this one to work.  I read through several blogs about visual tree and its datacontext and Placement target.Tag, I cant figure out where to include the tag property. Please guide me so that I can establish proper bindings. I am fairly new and this website has been of great help.

### In my MainWindow.xaml

```
 <ListView.ContextMenu >
   <ContextMenu Name="menuListContext" >
 <MenuItem Header="Reset" Name="menuReset" Command="{Binding ResetCmd}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}" >
<MenuItem Header="Filter By"   ItemsSource="{Binding ChildFilterMenuItems}">  
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>                                   
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding  Header, Mode=TwoWay}" />  
   <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=  ChildFilterMenuItems}"/>
   <Setter Property= "Command" Value= "{Binding DataContext.FilterByCmd, RelativeSource   ={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=DataContext}" />
   <Setter Property="Tag" Value= "{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/> 
  </Style>
 </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>

  </ContextMenu >
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

### MainViewModel.xaml

```
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// The menu item selected from FilterBy Menu.
       /// </summary>
       public string SelectedItem {get;set;}

     public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuClass> ChildFilterMenuItems
     {
        get
        {
            return _childFilterMenuItems;

        }

        set
        {
            _childFilterMenuItems = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged("ChildFilterMenuItems");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>      
    public MainViewModel()
    {  _childFilterMenuItems = new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuClass>(); 
       //populates the menuitems for FilterBy
       PopulateFilterBy  
       FilterByCmd = new RelayCommand(() => FilterByMenu(), () => true);
    }
    private void FilterByMenu()
    {
        try
        {
          string MenuName = GetExactName(SelectedItem);
         }
```

### ContextMenuClass.cs

```
public class ContextMenuClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields

    private ObservableCollection<ContextMenuClass> _filterItems;

    private string _header;

    private bool _isEnabled;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the header.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The header.</value>
    public string Header
    {
        get
        {
            return _header;
        }
        set
        {
            _header = value; OnPropertyChanged("Header");
        }
    }



    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
             _isEnabled = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuClass> ChildFilterMenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            return (_filterItems = _filterItems ??
             new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuClass>());
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the SelectedItem.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The header.</value>
    public object SelectedMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentItem = Header;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMenuItem");

        }

    }       
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private object _currentItem;

    /// <summary>
    /// Safely raises the PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property">The property name.</param>

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string Property)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: What do you mean by the 'selected' menu item?  Menus in WPF have no notion of a 'selected' item.  Are you referring to a menu item that has been clicked/invoked, or a checkable menu item which is 'checked'?

Comment: Yes. The menuitem on the FilterBy menu that has been clicked by the user.

Comment: Yes , what you say makes sense. The FilterByCmd command is invoked by a list of menuitems. I need the name of the menu item that invoked this command in my  FilterBy() method in my mainviewmodel for further implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which `ContextMenuClass` corresponds to the menu item that was clicked, you should modify your `CommandParameter` setter as follows:

```
<Setter Property="CommandParameter"
        Value="{Binding}" />
```

And then change your `FilterByCmd` from a `RelayCommand` to a `RelayCommand<ContextMenuClass>`:

```
FilterByCmd = new RelayCommand<ContextMenuClass>(FilterByMenu, _ => true);
```

And add a `ContextMenuClass` parameter to your `FilterByMenu` method:

```
private void FilterByMenu(ContextMenuClass selectedItem)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: sorry pressed enter on my previous comment ...FilterByCmd = new RelayCommand<MenuItem>(FilterByMenu); It did not work. It did not come to my mind that I was supposed to use the object that I created and not a windows control. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={ RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={ x:Type Window}}, Path= DataContext.MyListItemCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

The list is therefore `MyList` and the command is `MyListItemCommand` with command parameter being an actual item from the `MyList` (because `Value="{Binding}"` returns the actual list item).

This also means you would need to write `MyListItemCommand` (which implements `ICommand` interface) class which would manage which list item is currently checked (please note that also multiple items can be checked at the same time in this case).

Comment: Also please note that MyListItemCommand is not a property of the list items. It is a property of the ViewModel in which this whole code snippet is located.